# Recommended way to move elements of array to top level in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array: `[['TEST1'], ['TEST2'], ['TEST3'], ['TEST4'], ['TEST5']]` and I want to move all the elements to the "top" level of the array, so it would end up like so:

```
['TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3', 'TEST4', 'TEST5']
```

I have a few mockups below, but I'm wondering what the recommended route might be.

```
var test = [['TEST1'], ['TEST2'], ['TEST3'], ['TEST4'], ['TEST5']];
var testarr = [];

test.forEach(function(e){
  testarr.push(e[0]);
})
console.log(testarr);
```

Or

```
var test = [['TEST1'], ['TEST2'], ['TEST3'], ['TEST4'], ['TEST5']];

for (i = 0; n = test.length, i < n; i++){
  test[i] = test[i][0]
}
console.log(test);
```

Output of both:

```
[ 'TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3', 'TEST4', 'TEST5' ]
```

Comment: i am sure, there is a dupe target.

Comment: _"what the recommended route might be"_ Whichever route works best for you

Comment: Same question with native solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: You might want to look at [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865025/218196) for inspiration.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Well a solution I put together in my ignorance might end up performing very poorly down the road as it scales up. I'm just trying to get a feel for proper solutions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd either use reduce, or destructure it in a es6 environment

```
let test = [['TEST1'], ['TEST2'], ['TEST3'], ['TEST4'], ['TEST5']];
console.log(test.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), []));
console.log([].concat(...test));
```

If you have a multidimensional array, you could use

```
const flat = e => e.reduce(
    (a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flat(b) : b), []
);
```

Comment: For the multidimensional array, how would to use this?

Comment: Let res = flat(test); @DavidMetcalfe

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

ES6

```
var out = test.map(el => el[0]);
```

ES5

```
var out = test.map(function (el) {
  return el[0];
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/99o82oso/)**

Answer (score 2):

I'd stick with the first approach. It is much more concise, and less likely to fail. The second is somewhat difficult to understand if you're going in not knowing what it is supposed to do.

That being said, if you aren't just doing this to learn and actually plan to use this code for something, I recommend going with one of the proposed solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript) thread instead. My pick of the litter:

```
var arrays = [['TEST1'], ['TEST2'], ['TEST3'], ['TEST4'], ['TEST5']];
var result = [].concat.apply([], arrays);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is much cleaner and doesn't open up the possibility of bugs that can creep in using the counter in the second approach. This is the exact reason that `.forEach()` is preferred over traditional counting loops with arrays.

Having said that, the better approach would be to use **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** as this works very much like `.forEach()`, but returns a new array, saving you the trouble of explicitly declaring one and removing the need to `push()` into the right index of the original array:

```js
var test = [['TEST1'], ['TEST2'], ['TEST3'], ['TEST4'], ['TEST5']];
var testarr = test.map(e => { return e[0]; } );
console.log(testarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is array flattening and can be done by:

```
var array = [['TEST1'], ['TEST2'], ['TEST3'], ['TEST4'], ['TEST5']]
[].concat.apply([], array);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case when you want to change array in different array, the tool for the job is `map` function instead of `forEach`. It is cleaner because you don't need additional variable declaration before, and you can use poor functions inside.

```
var testarr = test.map(function(e){
 return e[0];
});
```

`forEach` function purpose is to loop over an array, not change it. Such looping can be used for doing side effects, but in this particular case, you don't want the side effects but clean and poor transformation between two arrays, and for that use `map`.

Comment: `.map` is not an operator. It's a method of `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below method

```js
const input = [
  ['TEST1'],
  ['TEST2'],
  ['TEST3'],
  ['TEST4'],
  ['TEST5']
]
function flattenDeep(input) {
    return input.reduce((accu, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? accu.concat(flattenDeep(val)):accu.concat(val), []);
}

console.log(flattenDeep(input));
```